# Xamarin Forms WebView Performance

Tags: c#, performance, webview, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm using a `WebView` to display the contents of emails.

I use the following `XAML` to bind the `WebView` to an `HTML` string:

```
        <WebView Grid.Column="1">
            <WebView.Source>
                <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding HtmlBody}"/>
            </WebView.Source>
        </WebView>
```

This all works fine on Android but when I use this code in a UWP app it is about 8-10 times slower than the Android version.  Sometimes it's painfully slow.

I have an email whose content is about 121K in size which take about 12 seconds to display after `HtmlBody` is set in the view model.

Has anyone else noticed this performance issue and come up with a workaround?

Would I be better off not using the `WebView` and creating my own instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem was not to use the built-in Xamarin `WebView` control.

I created a custom renderer for the UWP `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView` control in my Xamarin app.

This has been working fine without any performance issues.

Comment: Sample code could have been nice in case someone experienced the same problem :)